# Place for creating folder in linux?

Tags: linux, security, filesystems

Today i have been interested in answers on this:
where you create your work folder in linux?
In your `/home` directory or in `/usr/share/your_name'` or in another place?
And how do you think, what is the best practice to select folders for your own projects, photography, docs and etc.
And how to make my project folders more protected?

I make folders in my `home` directory.

Comment: what you mean by **make project folders more protected**? By setting appropriate permissions you can protect your files, except for super-user. If super-user too shouldn't check, talk to admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/home directory is good choice, during installation you also have a choice of encrypting /home directory if you're doing ubuntu setup.

So /home and subdirectories under that makes sense. /user directory is basically for general software installation.

For any linux file structure will be similar to following link: http://blogs.digitss.com/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-debian-file-system-organization/